# Area 51 link on Main 404's

Tags: bug, stackexchange

I recently learned about Ask Patents through a [meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284185/242209) which discussed the SE sites which did not go through Area 51.  That being said, there is still a [link](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/patents.stackexchange.com) to the Ask Patents Area 51 proposal on main which 404's.

Should this be removed or the link corrected?

Comment: The link can't be fixed since there is indeed no proposal.

Comment: It should be deleted.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288459/bug-report-on-ask-patents I reported that on SE beta. Maybe it helps.

Comment: One small question - where's this link?

Comment: @Oded Homepage, site stats.

Comment: I deleted the se meta post, but I don't yet believe you would ever have noticed without it.

Comment: @DonQuiKong why did you delete the meta.se post?

Comment: Because it got -3 and a lot of close votes. Apparently SE monitors all bugs on all sites. Or so they say. Whatever, rly.